# How to only display the correct route to exit of Maze in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop

So I have created a maze solver which finds the routes to the end however how can I make it so that if a route leads to a dead end, it is then rewritten to " " empty spaces. Below is my solver maze method.

Thank you all, The solution from @Leo Aso did the trick.

```
   private boolean solveMaze(int coorda, int coordb) { 
    return solveMaze(coorda, coordb, 0, 0);
}

private boolean solveMaze(int coorda, int coordb, int dx, int dy) { 

    switch (myMaze[coorda][coordb]) {
        case '#': case 'X': return false;
        case 'E': return true;
    }

    myMaze[coorda][coordb] = 'X';

    if (dx >= 0 && solveMaze(coorda + 1, coordb, +1, 0) || // W
        dx <= 0 && solveMaze(coorda - 1, coordb, -1, 0) || // E
        dy >= 0 && solveMaze(coorda, coordb + 1, 0, +1) || // S
        dy <= 0 && solveMaze(coorda, coordb - 1, 0, -1)) { // N
        return true;
    }       

    myMaze[coorda][coordb] = ' ';
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Question updated with output and required output.

Comment: You've posted your expected output, but can you also post the output that you are actually getting, so that it is clear what exactly the problem is?

Comment: @LeoAso both expected and actual output is shown.

Comment: How are you invoking your method?

Comment: Try my method and see if it works.

Comment: Don't change the code on the question with the code in the answer, because that way who arrives here don't know what the original codes looked like. Just accepting the answer you are already stating that the code in the answer solved the problem, but if you want you can update the question and add some text in the end saying that the code from the answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if it works.

```
private boolean solveMaze(int coorda, int coordb) { 
    return solveMaze(coorda, coordb, 0, 0);
}

private boolean solveMaze(int coorda, int coordb, int dx, int dy) { 

    switch (myMaze[coorda][coordb]) {
        case '#': case 'X': return false;
        case 'E': return true;
    }

    myMaze[coorda][coordb] = 'X';

    if (dx >= 0 && solveMaze(coorda + 1, coordb, +1, 0) || // W
        dx <= 0 && solveMaze(coorda - 1, coordb, -1, 0) || // E
        dy >= 0 && solveMaze(coorda, coordb + 1, 0, +1) || // S
        dy <= 0 && solveMaze(coorda, coordb - 1, 0, -1)) { // N
        return true;
    }       

    myMaze[coorda][coordb] = ' ';
    return false;
}
```

The problem you had is that you didn't ensure that the recursion wasn't allowed to go back in the direction it came from. If you allow this, then *all* paths lead to the exit, since turning around is a valid move. That's where `dx` and `dy` come in. When you go east/west, dx is +1/-1, and when you go north/south, dy is -1/+1, respectively. The big `if` statement ensures that you won't go in a direction if you were just coming from that way e.g. don't move east if you just moved west.

Answer (score -1):

You could maybe write an if statement that understood what a dead end was. So it would mainly search for where three different directions were '#'. Then you could maybe have an if statement that said if deadend is true, trace your steps back and remove the x values.